# HTML5 video 'hickup' with jQuery .delay()

Tags: jquery, performance, html5-video

When I use a HTML5 video with some `.delay()` functions by jQuery. I have some 'hickups' in the movie... This happens on Chrome, Firefox and Safari (not tested on IE), all at exactly the same moment (when the `.delay` occurs)

(so it isn't a performance issue)

Example of the problem: http://kubrickolo.gy

EDIT:
It happens at his moment: `$('#logoSmall').delay(1900).fadeIn(900);`

Comment: Should we debug your entire site or will you post relevant code here?!

Comment: :-S no of course not. There isn't really any code to mention. (see my little edit) the point is that when a .delay() gets triggered, the video 'hicks' so I thought: maybe anybody is familiar with this problem and maybe he/she has a solution...

Comment: Post your relevant code. Links break. For now, I have a suggestion and a question. Using HTML5 video has led me to occasional cross-browser problems, which (I think) I solved by putting the sources in this order: webm, ogg, mp4. Why are two of the sources commented out?

Comment: Also, you may want to fix your if-IE-insert-script sections. The second one is not comment syntax (and good thing: if it was, non-IE browsers wouldn't load jQuery). You might want to load 2.0.3, *then* use the if-IE comment, though I'm not sure if this will override correctly. Which leads me to my next question: what are you doing in non-IE that requires jQuery 2.0.3?

Comment: @trojansdestroy good point, I have a reason for doing this with a bad argumentation: "I assume: newer = better" I'm going to try to remove the .delay and have them in the animation, somehow I can't find it :-S